# Python sockets not responsered

Tags: python, sockets

my code send a http request using sockets and then save the response.It works for me yesterday, but today i cant receive response. I need to use sockets not httplib or urllib. I dont know if code is not working or my python install is crazy. thanks!

```
import socket
import logging


def get_http(target, port, request):
    """
     Method that sends an HTTP request and returns the response

    :param target:
    :type target:

    :return:
    :rtype: str
    """
    try:
        s = socket.create_connection((target, port))
        s.sendall(request.encode())
        response = repr(s.recv(2024).decode())
    except socket.error as e:
        logging.error('Failed to create connection: %s', e.strerror)
    return response
```

---

```
import lib.netgrab as n


class Probe():

    def __init__(self):
        super(Probe, self).__init__()

    def prueba(self):
        n.get_http('www.website.com', 80, 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')

pr = Probe()
re = pr.prueba()
print(re)
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I cant print the response because i cant obtain response :S, Its like response is null. But yesterday it works and i obtain the http header with print(re)

Comment: per the rfc you are missing the CRLF in your "HEAD" Request-Line http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5

Comment: Yes i forgot that, but still not working :(

Comment: Have you tried on a different server? Also have you tried setting the Host header?

Comment: I think that the problem is the "return response", i fput a print(response) it works, but not for return. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot your return statement, please update:

```
def prueba(self):
    return n.get_http('www.website.com', 80, 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
```